# Problem protecting endpoints using antMatchers in Spring security(Spring Boot 3.0.7 & JDK 17)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I want delete operations on /api/v1/posts/1 to be performed by only ADMIN.
Here is the code .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, `"/api/v1/posts/{id}").hasRole("ADMIN")`

My Bean is:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/v1/posts/{id}").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
```

The line following has a compile error that I don't understand

```
 httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Spring Security 6.0 (so along with Spring Boot 3), `antMatchers`, `mvcMatchers()`,`and()`, and as well as several other methods were deprecated. A method `requestMatchers` was provided, along with their `Customizer` approach of configuring input arguments. These all seem to be issues with your code, please update and read the documentation and update your code!

The following should be a fix to your code implementing all of the above:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity
                .cors(withDefaults())
                .csrf(csrf->csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests(authorize->authorize
                     .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/v1/posts/{id}")
                     .hasRole("ADMIN")
                     .anyRequest()
                     .authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement
                     .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
```

Comment: Happy to help, I had this issue migrating from Spring Boot 2->3! Just mark it as answered please!